# smartgwt listgridfield with boolean type with checkbox in field header

Tags: checkbox, smartgwt, listgrid

I've listgridfield in which I need to show checkboxes. So, I just set that field like

```
listGridFieldChk.setFieldDataType(ListGridFieldType.BOOLEAN);
```

It working fine like I want, only thing which I need now is checkbox in header with the same field. So when user want to check or uncheck all checkbox at once will do with this.

[image]

I know about the listGrid property which put checkbox field at first column

```
thisGrid.setSelectionAppearance(SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX);
```

But this will not helpful for me, I need it at custom level.

Comment: _But this will not helpful for me, I need it at custom level._ Can you please elaborate this?

Comment: Hello @RAS, thanks 4 yr response, As you show in the image there is CHK on header at that position I need to put checkbox with the field type BOOLEAN.

Comment: But that functionality is already provided by SmartGWT.

Comment: I think you are talking about thisGrid.setSelectionAppearance(SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX);
but I want that for not to selecting the grid row that's why above line not helpful for me